# VBA-equivalent to pressing "tab" inside a textbox or shape?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation called from Excel and want to change the text in one of the shapes. It's a table of contents and when I do it manually, I can write the text on the left, press tab once and the cursor jumps to the far right where I can write "Page". How do I do this with VBA, the "tab" part? I know I can write into a shape like this:

```
myPresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("shp2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Development of X in Year 2019"
```

My workaround is that replace the part I wanna change, which is the year:

```
myPresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("shp1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(myPresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("shp1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "2019", yearVariable)
```

But if someone manually deletes or changes the year, it doesn't work anymore so I don't want to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean just using `vbTab`?

```
myPresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("shp2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Development of X in Year" & vbTab & "2019"
```